# Delete multiple cards in a list in Trello

Tags: trello

Is it possible to delete multiple cards from a list in Trello all at once? It's a pain to select each one and delete.

Comment: Unfortunately the accepted answer is not really correct. It's the shortcut to only `archive` those cards, not the shortcut to `delete` them.

Comment: Unfortunately the current accepted answer is wrong too. Authorizing a third party to access all your data is not read solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been suffering with the difficulty Trello puts in deleting cards for a long time, now I've put together this [Batch actions for Trello](https://github.com/fiatjaf/batch-for-trello) almost exclusively to allow me to delete a lot of cards.

You use it totally from the client side, there is no server. Just authorize your Trello account, you'll be shown a list of boards, select one, them multi-select the cards you want and select the "Delete" action.

It is a work in progress, but it can already perform deletions.

Comment: Asking an authorization to access all Trello data is not a real solution.

Comment: Suggest a "real" solution, then, @spartacus. If you're going to say "a browser extension", please be aware that it would be very much in control of your Trello data (and a big part of your computer resources) if authorized to run in your browser.

Comment: While true, @fiatjaf, an extension also exposes user to risk, at least that has a feedback mechanism where people can review the extension and there is a possibility of enforcement by delisting the extension if it is found to be abusive

Answer (score 7):

Just use shortcuts. You can select the first one that you want to delete and the press on `C` as fast as possible. I think it's faster than even doing the multiple select and then deleting a card. Also press `?` to find more useful shortcuts.

Comment: nice, that was pretty cool.

Comment: Start using shortcuts in other webapps.. use `?` in gmail, reader, dropbox, docs...

Comment: I use shortcuts extensively in Gmail & Google docs, didn't realize Trello had them as well

Comment: @Lipis But it doesn't delete the cards. It only `archive`s them.

Answer (score 1):

Found this nice chrome browser extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multiselect-for-trello/jlnfnpelianecpjoeahaeihmkhnkakof?pli=1&authuser=1&_ind=category%252Fextensions&_asi=1

### Trello Multiselect

Manage and modify multiple cards at once
**NEW: You can now add/remove Custom Fields to multiple cards**

Access the power of performing an action on multiple Trello cards at once. Select multiple cards or an entire list, open the Actions menu and apply an action to every selected card. It's just that simple.

Features included:

- Check the cards manually or with Ctrl / Command (OS X) + click.
- Select cards individually or the entire list. List selection even works with applied filters.
- Assign multiple labels, or remove them, for all cards selected.
- Assign multiple members, or remove them, for all cards selected.
- Move/Copy cards to another Board, List or even position in list.
- Append/Prepend text to cards title/body.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer has been downvoted. The linked extension appears to be fine enough, although I haven't tested it.

Comment: @fiatjaf the extension works great. A small amount to pay for something that would be useful in core for Trello.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this Workaround:

1. Archive the list of cards you want do delete
2. Copy the entire board with the option "Keep cards" checked

Doing that, the new board will not have the archived cards. **PLEASE NOTE** that this is a (ugly) workaround. Since you copied the board, your board and all your cards will be actual new board and cards, with new permalinks and all. They'll **NOT** have their activity log anymore (including comments on the card). You'll also have to add your team members once again. This solution may or may not suit your needs.